# Pygame switching from fullscreen to normal does not work

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

im currently trying to have a setting to switch from windowed mode and fullscreen. But after getting into fullscreen and trying to go back, the game bugs really weird and sticks to the topleft corner

Btw:
display_width = 1280
display_height = 720

```
    elif (Settings_Menu == True):
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        screen.blit(settingsscreen, (0,0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    if checkbox1.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        if(Fullscreen == False):
                            Fullscreen = True
                            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
                        else:
                            Fullscreen = False
                            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen) to switch between fullscreen and windowed displays.

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if event.button == 1:
            if checkbox1.collidepoint(event.pos):
                pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()
```

The documentation [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen) mentions that display driver support "is not great" when using Pygame 1, but it should work for the following display drivers in Pygame 2:

- windows (Windows)
- x11 (Linux/Unix)
- wayland (Linux/Unix)
- cocoa (OSX/Mac)

However, at the time of writing this answer, there is a bug in `toggle_fullscreen` for Windows:

[display.toggle_fullscreen does not work when toggling a maximized window to fullscreen #2380](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/2380)

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in pygame 2.0 and 2.0.1. Reported on github [here](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/2360)

The author there also found a workaround where you quit pygame between switching fullscreen.

Unfortunately, the toggle_fullscreen documentation is wrong. It does not work on windows. [Reported on github](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/2380)

Now you might think- pygame has way too many problems with fullscreen, which is reasonable. But they are being fixed. I submitted a [patch](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2460) for your issue which was merged a week ago and will be included in pygame 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem and fixed it with:

```
pygame.display.set_mode(size,pygame.SCALED)
```

and then i wrote `pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()` and worked.